# Odd Resolution in Unet Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I new to this domain , recently i am building unet for image similarity , when i started the training im getting concatenate error as two  are of differant shapes(35,81,81,3) and (35,80,80,3)

```
def build_generator():
    input = Input((None,None,3))
    
    # Encoder path
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    # Decoder path
    up6 = Conv2DTranspose(512, 2, strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(drop5)
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2DTranspose(256, 2, strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3, up7], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2DTranspose(128, 2, strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2, up8], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2DTranspose(64, 2, strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1, up9], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(3, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    return Model(inputs=input,outputs=conv10,name='generator')
```

Above is the Unet architecture , is there any way to pass variable sized input, i dont want to  resize the image.